# `jq` selection based on condition of different levels

Tags: jq

I'd like to select the following node in a long json file.

The conditions are `"locator": "mmc1"` and `"#name": "section-title"`. This nested structure makes the jq query very complex. Notice that I have to specify things like "locator" and "section-title" multiple times.

```
.. | .["$$"]?
 | select((.[]? | ."#name" == "section-title"?) and (..[]? | .locator? | test("mmc[0-9]+")?))
 | [
(..[]? | select(.locator? | test("mmc[0-9]+")?) | .locator)
, (.[] | select(."#name" == "section-title") | ._)
] | @tsv
```

Could anybody let me know how to make the query simpler in jq yet make sure its function is exact the same as the original query? Just making the following simplified test input producing the same output should not be considered as an equivalent query. Thanks.

```
...
              "$$": [
                {
                  "#name": "label",
                  "_": "Appendix A"
                },
                {
                  "#name": "section-title",
                  "$": {
                    "id": "sectitle0145"
                  },
                  "_": "Supplementary data"
                },
                {
                  "#name": "para",
                  "$": {
                    "id": "p0210",
                    "view": "all"
                  },
                  "$$": [
                    {
                      "#name": "__text__",
                      "_": "The following is the supplementary data related to this article:"
                    },
                    {
                      "#name": "display",
                      "$$": [
                        {
                          "#name": "e-component",
                          "$": {
                            "id": "ec1"
                          },
                          "$$": [
                            {
                              "#name": "link",
                              "$": {
                                "locator": "mmc1",
                                "type": "simple",
                                "role": "http://data.elsevier.com/vocabulary/ElsevierContentTypes/46.1",
                                "href": "pii:S2212877817302818/mmc1",
                                "id": "aep-link-id8"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
...
```

See the output below.

```
$ jq '.. | .["$$"]? | select((.[]? | ."#name" == "section-title"?) and (..[]? | .locator? | test("mmc[0-9]+")?)) | [ (..[]? | select(.locator? | test("mmc[0-9]+")?) | .locator) , (.[] | select(."#name" == "section-title") | ._) ] | @tsv' < 1.json
"mmc1\tSupplementary data"
$ cat 1.json
            {
              "$$": [
                {
                  "#name": "label",
                  "_": "Appendix A"
                },
                {
                  "#name": "section-title",
                  "$": {
                    "id": "sectitle0145"
                  },
                  "_": "Supplementary data"
                },
                {
                  "#name": "para",
                  "$": {
                    "id": "p0210",
                    "view": "all"
                  },
                  "$$": [
                    {
                      "#name": "__text__",
                      "_": "The following is the supplementary data related to this article:"
                    },
                    {
                      "#name": "display",
                      "$$": [
                        {
                          "#name": "e-component",
                          "$": {
                            "id": "ec1"
                          },
                          "$$": [
                            {
                              "#name": "link",
                              "$": {
                                "locator": "mmc1",
                                "type": "simple",
                                "role": "http://data.elsevier.com/vocabulary/ElsevierContentTypes/46.1",
                                "href": "pii:S2212877817302818/mmc1",
                                "id": "aep-link-id8"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
```

Comment: It is not sufficient to just wrap it in `{}`. There are `...`'s that you will need to remove.

Comment: Try it again. I pasted the command and it output.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Select _what_ node? How do `"locator": "mmc1"` and `"#name": "section-title"` relate to the result you want? Your output doesn't seem to match the definition of "node". Please clarify what you're trying to get out of this.

Comment: Just select the information that is currently printed. In this case the locator and its description text.

Comment: Still can't reproduce `"mmc1\tSupplementary data"` using jq 1.6

Comment: You've shown the jq code that you don't want, but you haven't described the "condition" that you do want.  Also, it's not clear why you've essentially repeated 1.json. Also, as per the [mcve] guidelines, it would probably help if your example was more on the minimal side. Please remember that just because a question is clear to you does not mean it is clear to others :-) . Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the `"locator"` value off of all objects unconditionally, you could use this:

```
..|objects.locator|strings
```

To find all objects with `#name == "section-title"` and select the `_` value:

```
..|select(objects."#name" == "section-title")._
```

Putting it all together:

```
[(..|objects.locator|strings), (..|select(objects."#name" == "section-title")._)] | @tsv
```

https://jqplay.org/s/xHWg8aGSSS

Comment: No. You need to assume locator and section-title appear many times in the json file. Only when they appear in a node like what I showed, they will be extracted. I basically need an equivalent but simplified jq query as mine.

Comment: You need to explicitly state what the conditions are that you're trying to get values... you cannot expect us to interpret what your code is doing, it's your job to do so if you want help from us... `"Just select the information that is currently printed. In this case the locator and its description text."` this does just that...

Comment: In case you didn't get it the first time from my comment in the question, it is not clear what your objective is... PLEASE CLARIFY

Answer (score -1):

The following is simpler in at least some respects, produces the desired result, and seems to reflect the requirements:

```
..
| .["$$"]?
| (.. | objects | .locator | strings | select(test("mmc[0-9]+")) ) as $locator
| (.. | objects | select(.["#name"] == "section-title") | ._) as $st
| [$locator, $st]
| @tsv
```

Comment: Does this guarantee that locator and st must from the same object? In other words, when there are multiple locators and sts in the same json file, but only one pair of them is in the same object, this query will only extract that pair but not any other combinations of locators and sts? I don't see how this code can guarantee this.

Comment: The problem with your "requirements" is precisely that it's not clear what you mean by "same object".   JSON has a very precise definition of what an object is.  Your input has many of them.

Comment: See this simple example similar to yours. I can not extract the object with both "a" and "b" fields as number.  `jq '. | (..| objects | .a | numbers) as $a | (..| objects | .b | numbers) as $b | [ $a, $b ]' <<< '[[{"a": 10}], [{"b": 20}], [{"a": 1, "b": 2}]]'`. My requirement is clear. The simplified query must be the same as my original query in terms of the function. That is, no matter what the input is, the output must be same. It is not sufficient to make the output the same just for my simplied input in the original post.